# How to get window foo to refresh when bar is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So i have 2 windows.. my main browser window (foo), then it has a href that calls a bit of JS that will make a mini window (bar) pop up.. The mini window contains a form which posts to itself and query a database and updates fields.. It works fine.

```
if($edit_type == "email")
{
    if($update == true)
    {
        $form_email = $_POST['form_email'];
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
        UPDATE users
        SET `email` = '$form_email' 
        WHERE username = '$username';
        ");     
    }

    //Other code to run when the page hasnt been posted
}
```

My question is, when its submitted, and the DB is queried, would it be possible to close bar automatically and then refresh foo to see the updated data?

PS.

The script im using to open my popup is as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
  <!--
   function myPopup(target) 
   {
    window.open( target, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 600, width = 600, resizable = 0" )   
   }
   //-->
</script>
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to refer to the main window from your `bar` pop-up.

`window.opener` in this case is your `foo`.

```
if(window.opener && !window.opener.closed) { //Check whether opener is open
   window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href ; //Refresh main
   window.close();                                             //Close itself
}
```

Comment: It should actually work. You can create a button and test the code above when clicking it.

Comment: So how do i set window.opener to my foo class and im guessing the JS will go into the bar class?